# Is there an inkit.org style diagramming app that will produce a Rails or Node.js skeleton app with scaffolding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, user-interface, scaffolding, flowchart

I'm trying to figure out if there are any applications (SaaS or otherwise) that offer a basic graphical user interface for building out all the necessary scaffolding of a Rails or Node.js app from a flow-chart type of interface?

I remember Visual Studio had something like this for building database structures...why wouldn't there be something that does this for Rails or Node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RailsModels](http://www.railsmodels.com) purports to do this, but I find the interface is quite cumbersome.

If you just want to generate the diagrams from existing models for visualization, [RailRoad](http://railroad.rubyforge.org/) and [RubyMine Data Sources Tool](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/data-sources-tool-window.html) can do this. But, neither offer a method for generating models from the GUI.

You are thinking of the [Entity Model Designer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/10/11/entity-designer-improvements-preview.aspx) (or possibly the older [dataset designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171897.aspx)), and I do not know of any Rails tools that offer similar functionality. As to why, I am not sure. I could comment, but it would be a guess, and probably be flamebait.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'll be marking this as the correct answer, but I'll hold out a bit to see if anyone has a better suggestion first.  

I would use RailsModels more if it didn't throw errors so often.  But yeah, that's exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/preston/railroady

RailRoady, i believe its only > Rails 3 though...

Comment: Hey David, RailRoady looks promising for drawing diagrams of existing Models/Routes, but it doesn't allow you to construct them from a GUI like the Visual Studio table designer does.  However, I just found out that RubyMine offers something similar to this in its Model Dependency Viewer.  You can create Models and relate them from a GUI.  Thanks for your input though!